# how do I un-cache a cached webpage

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, meta-tags

I used meta tags to cache a webpage. Now I have updated the webpage and the updates wont display on the cached page( the index page).  The new index-page will not display unless I clear my Internet browsing history.

how do I undo this cache that stored the webpage?

... so that someone who previously visited the webpage does not have to clear their internet-browsing history in order to view the updated index page.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is the index page the entry point of your WebApp?
If yes, you should not mark it as cacheable.

Comment: use <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> to force your browser to always load the page from your server

Comment: The index page is the home page of the website.   so if i place the code that you showed me, on it the index page, it should stop the previous cached index page from caching and always display the new updated page?

Answer (score 0):

### Found a new method

1. Go to devtools
2. Got to the "Application" tab
3. Go to Storage
4. Scroll down a bit
5. If you scroll down you get more options un-check all except Cache Storage
6. There will be a button with text "Clear Site Data" Click that